# On which side of a one to many relationship I should call persist method to persist both sides

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence

I am using Hibernate and I have these two classes.

```
public class ApplicantYear{

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "APPLICANT_ID")
private Applicant applicant;
.
.
.

}

public class Applicant {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "applicant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
 private Set<ApplicantYear> applicantYears = new HashSet<ApplicantYear>();
.
.
.

}

Public void testPersistence(){

 Applicant appl= new ....
 ApplicantYear applYear= new(appl, ...)
```

//should I use appl.persist() or applYear.persist() so that both sides will be persisted //at once?

```
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said for example in [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html), operations are cascaded to the associated entities. In your case this means that calling

```
entityManager.persist(instanceOfApplicant)
```

will cascade persist operation also to the elements of `applicantYears`list. Functionality is similar for refresh operation.

Comment: Thank you @Mikko. Do the other way round would work? i.e if I use entityManager.persist(instanceOfApplicantYear)

Comment: Depends about what you mean with 'work'. For sure it does not cascade persist, so if instanceOfApplicantYear have new instance referenced by applicant, it will not work.

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about persist.